# Response.direct to a specific instance of a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

What i want:
          pass values to public properties in a Page and call that specific instance, i cant use query variables coz that can be manipulated, also there are a lot of properties so keeping in session would be memory intensive, is there any way to assign the properties to the page and response.redirect to the page.

I had a look at the following post but dint get much of any idea.

[Response.Redirect to Class that inherits from UI.Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151744/response-redirect-to-class-that-inherits-from-ui-page)

Does anybody know any solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about SEO on the second/new page you could try Server.Transfer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes **you can use query by encrypt it**. Do not make you life so difficult with complex thinks, just encrypt it, and decrypt it with error checking and that's all.

here is a sample code for encrypting query strings: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33350/Encrypting-Query-Strings

you can also make a cross-page postback that check for the valid of the data, see this example:

[Cross-page postbacks and back again retaining data from source page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736445/cross-page-postbacks-and-back-again-retaining-data-from-source-page/3736506#3736506)